# filter class/subfolder with pytorch ImageFolder

Tags: python, pytorch

Here's my folder structure

```
image-folders/
   ├── class_0/
   |   ├── 001.jpg
   |   ├── 002.jpg
   └── class_1/
   |   ├── 001.jpg
   |   └── 002.jpg
   └── class_2/
       ├── 001.jpg
       └── 002.jpg
```

By using `ImageFolder` from torchvision, I can create dataset with this syntax :
`dataset = ImageFolder("image-folders",...)`

But this will read the entire subfolder and create 3 target classes. I don't want to include the class_2 folder, I want my dataset to only contains class_0 and class_1 only, is there any way to achieve this besides delete/move the class_2 folder?

Comment: no ..... but using your custom dataloader , u can achieve this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by using [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) of the original full `ImageFolder` dataset:

```py
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import Subset

# construct the full dataset
dataset = ImageFolder("image-folders",...)
# select the indices of all other folders
idx = [i for i in range(len(dataset)) if dataset.imgs[i][1] != dataset.class_to_idx['class_s']]
# build the appropriate subset
subset = Subset(dataset, idx)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The .imgs attribute is really helpful :)

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy it is a good thing you pruned the last class. If you were to remove another class - you might have issues with the labels...

Comment: I've been using the code like this to filter any class I want  
```idx = [i for i in range(len(dataset)) if dataset.imgs[i][1] in ["class0","class1"]]```
What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy I'll leave it to you as an exercise ;)

Comment: Oh, I forgot the class_to_idx part in my comment. Also I think this will be the problem.
Let's say I have 5 classes, the ImageFolder will give label 0,1,2,3,4 to each class.
If I remove the the class in the middle (let's say class 1 and 2), then my label will become 0,3,4.
 If I create Image Classification with that, then the label will be broken, so I need to reset the available of the classes to 0,1,2. Is that right?

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy +1 correct! you have a classification problem with 3 labels (0, 3, 4), but the CE loss will get gt labels 3 and 4 - outside the range of 0..`num_labels`.

Comment: Never thought someone else beside my math book to leave exercise for me hahahaha